# Why CSS files are affected by Application_BeginRequest in global asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to handle only for actions but looks like `Application_BeginRequest` method handles also `CSS`, images etc...

How to avoid it ?

Because sounds like I can't override content only for actions:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Maintenance.html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HttpApplication.BeginRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) "occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request."

So *any* request going through your ASP.NET pipeline will trigger this, not just *.aspx, etc.

You can't avoid it, but you can check the path of the requested file and perform and action as needed, like:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string file = Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower();
    if (file == ("/user/singin"))
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

Though there may be another way altogether to accomplish your goal (which isn't clear from your question).

Comment: yes it is exactly what I want. But I want to do it for action in mvc
I mean that the page like User/SignIn where SignIn is action and it doesn't have extensions.

Comment: @Sergey you can still use that... the `file` in that case will be something like '/user/signin'. There isn't necessarily going to be an extension. Just updated example.

Comment: @Sergey although I'd think you could do something in your controller, so you aren't running that if statement on every request!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict doing something only to web forms requests, I've used something like the following:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".aspx"){
         //stuff to do
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is exactly what I want. But I want to do it for action in mvc
I mean that the page like User/SignIn where SignIn is action and it doesn't have extensions. For the ASP.NET with excensions everything is clear, but for MVC Action it is not clear how to accomplish it.

Comment: this does not work if request is www.example.com but only if it is www.example.com/default.aspx

Comment: @giammin This should not have anything to do with what the request *looks* like but with what resource IIS has chosen to process the request.

Comment: @JayC just saying that this method is not accurate because it misses some web forms requests

Comment: @giammin, well, when I wrote this answer 5 years ago I think my answer was more accurate, though maybe I could be wrong.  I just tested on a newer project and it *still* worked  for `http://example.com/`, *however* newer projects apparently have built in tools for URL optimization, so  `http://example.com/Detault.aspx` becomes `http://example.com/Default`, and it does fail there.